# Change version of libssh2 and libssl2 in regular expression?

Tags: grep

I am trying to have my own bash script Frugghi issh script to generate libssl and libssh libraries for apple platforms. Reason why i want to try my own bash script is to fetch the recent libs and keep updated.

I have two bash scripts to detect the recent version of openssl and libssh2 libs:

```
    getLibssh2Version () {
  if type git >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    LIBSSH_VERSION=`git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2.git | egrep "libssh2-[0-9]+(\.[0-9])*[a-zA-Z]?$" | cut -f 2 -d - | sort -t . -r | head -n 1`
    LIBSSH_AUTO=true
}
```

and

```
    getOpensslVersion () {
  if type git >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    LIBSSL_VERSION=`git ls-remote --tags git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git | egrep "OpenSSL(_[0-9])+[a-zA-Z]?$" | cut -f 2,3,4 -d _ | sort -t _ -r | head -n 1 | tr _ .`
    LIBSSL_AUTO=true

}
```

But the first script fetches the Libssh2 of 1.9.0 version instead of 1.10.0 and the second script fetches OpenSSL of 1.1.1n series instead of 3.0.2 (though both are same). I guess it is something related to the regular expression defined . Can someone sort out this script error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first snippet:

- You're filtering the `1.10.0` version in your `egrep` with `(\.[0-9])*` which should be `(\.[0-9]+)*`.
- For numeric sorting on these subrevisions, `sort` needs more options: `-t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n`
- I've switched to not do reverse sorting but using `tail` instead of `head`, as reverse sorting somehow does not work with the other options (on my machine, at least).

Solution:

```
git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2.git | \
     egrep "libssh2-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*[a-zA-Z]?$" | \
     cut -f 2 -d - | sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n | tail -n 1
```

Output:

```
1.10.0
```

---

In the second snippet:

- Naming and punctuation changed from 1.x to 3.x versions, so they are filtered out by the `egrep`. Instead of `egrep "OpenSSL(_[0-9])+[a-zA-Z]?$"`, I'd naively use `egrep -i "OpenSSL([_.-][0-9])+[a-zA-Z]?$"`.
- Consequently, the version "extraction" with `cut` fails for the newer versions. Spontaneously, I chose to use `sed 's/.*openssl.//i'` to do the same.
- Again I've switched from using `head` to `tail`.
- **Note** that the `sort`ing suffers from the same problem as in the first snippet, i.e. when these subrevisions start rolling over, e.g. from `3.9...` to `3.10...`, you'll need to add the same options as above.

Solution:

```
git ls-remote --tags git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git | \
    egrep -i "OpenSSL([_.-][0-9])+[a-zA-Z]?$" | \
    sed 's/.*openssl.//i' | sort -t _ | tail -n 1 | tr _ .
```

Output:

```
3.0.2
```

Comment: thanks a lot ... Can you please explain why did you add [_.-] in "OpenSSL([_.-][0-9])+[a-zA-Z]?$"

Comment: @user16780334 Glad to have helped. This is because the `([_.-][0-9])+` is used to match revision and subrevision numbers including the separators. And if you look over the variations, the separators can be `_`, `-` and `.`. Since `-` has a special meaning in character classes, it needs to be put at the end.

Comment: Thanks again .. Your comment makes me more informative in regex. If you dont mind can i ask how a simple change like this changed from 1.x version to 3.x version? Also what does -i means after egrep?

Comment: @user16780334 Well the change may be small but for the result it changes a lot. In this case the original `egrep` regex simply filters out the 3.x versions so they don't show up. The `-i` means `egrep` should operate case insensitive due to `OpenSSL_1...` vs `openssl-3...`. For such common utils, you can always use `man` to find out about the commands, i.e. `man egrep` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need Perl style regex matching which does the `-oP` option of `grep`.

#### Getting the `libssh2` latest version.

```
git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2.git | grep -oP "libssh2-([\d.]*)" | tail -1 | grep -oP "(?<=-).*"
```

#### Getting the `openssl` latest version.

```
git ls-remote --tags git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git | grep -oP "openssl-([\d.]*)" | tail -1 | grep -oP "(?<=-).*"
```